# Two conditions for executing a Jquery function()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with the google maps API. My HTML looks like this:

```
<form id="searchTheme" method="get">
     <select class="form-control" name="thema" id="themaID">
          <option value="1">item1</option>
          ...
          <option value="5">item1</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="zoek">
</form>

<button id="allePois"> Alle POI&lsquo;s</button>
```

My javascript (jQuery) looks like this:

```
function initMap(x) {
    //some other code
    var controlUIMijnPOIS = document.getElementById('allePois');

    $('#searchTheme').submit(function() {
         //CODE to be executed (with the themaID passed by the form)
    }) 

    controlUIMijnPOIS.addEventListener('click', function() {
         //CODE to be executed (same code as above but themaID has no value, wich is fine)
    })
    //some other code
}
```

I could duplicate the code for both events (form submit and button click), but I want the same code to be executed if the form is submitted OR the button is clicked. (I don't want to have that whole bunch of code twice in my script)

So I'll get something like this:

```
$('#searchMyTheme').submit || controlUIMyPOIS.addEventListener('click') function(){
   //CODE to be executed.
}
```

Is that even possible and if so, how can I establish this?

Comment: can you explain more clearly,

Comment: and please try to put html code, and what function trying to run.

Comment: You want to attach 2 event to same listener? It seems normal thing to do. What problem are you facing?

Comment: Also, why are you using a mix of jQuery and native event listener code?

Comment: The answer depends on **why** you are doing this and **what you are trying to accomplish**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a single function and call it on your event handlers.

```
function your_func(){
 ...
}

$('#searchMyTheme').on('submit',your_func);
controlUIMyLocation.addEventListener('click',your_func);
```

When one is not present another presents and there will be no issue.